# Checking unique files in Windows directories

Tags: windows, windows-xp, batch

I have two directory on my D drive. `D:\1` and `D:\2`. Directory 1 and 2 and subdirectories have a bunch of files.

I need a batch file that will:

- Read each file in Directory 1 and check if the same file exists in Directory 2
- Avoids duplicates files
- Moves only those files which are not present in directory 2 to a different directory `C:\3` with the same folder structure.
- Read the next file, and so on.

At the end I have `C:\3` which has only the unique files from 1. I know I can drag and drop … but I need this in a batch file.

Answer (score 1):

```
robocopy "D:\dira" "D:\dirb" /MIR /XO /W:5 /V /LOG:"D:\dira\log.txt"
exit
```

save as `foo.cmd` and run it when you want, or schedule it in task manager

[source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

- /mir: Mirrors a directory tree
- /xo: Excludes older files.
- /w:5: Specifies the wait time between retries, in seconds
- /v: Produces verbose output, and shows all skipped files.
- /log: Writes the status output to the log file (overwrites the existing log file).

Comment: If you use `/W:5` you should also use `/R:x` (default retry value is 1.000.000). `/MT:x` is a second suggest i would made.

Comment: @nixda good catch

Comment: can script be edited rather than giving output to log.txt file, Missing file should directly copy to backup folder?

Comment: @KalimSayyed The log file just tells you what changes occurred and if there were no errors. It can write the log file to anywhere.

Comment: The issue is i have made a batch script to copy day older files from dir and subdir on basis of modified date and store into backup folder with same dir structure of root... Now many of the files are missing (not copied from source folder). Now i am requiring batch script to search for missing file which not copied...

Comment: @KalimSayyed robocopy will mirror the directory for you, only copying files that do not match. This will do what you want, unless I misunderstand.

Comment: raysta i want to copy only unidentical files..

Comment: So you want to compare two directories, identify mis-matches and then move those to a third directory?

Comment: yes...rastya..!!!

Comment: Check out [winmerge](http://winmerge.org/) and adjust your question to reflect what you're looking for.

Comment: windows 2008 if preferable. Xp can also do.

Comment: but winmerge will check only one folder at a time.. i want to check dir and subdirs.

Comment: This comment string is too long. Adjust your question to include your specific requirements

Comment: Hey !!! i have updated the question as per the requirement. Please help me with this..

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set "d1=D:\Login1"
set "d2=D:\Login2"
set "d3=D:\RESULT"

for /R "%d1%" %%F in ("*") do (
    if not exist "%d2%\%%~nxF" move "%%~fF" "%d3%"
)
```

As proposed by Kalim at https://superuser.com/questions/624007/by-searching-dir1-and-dir2-and-move-unique-file-from-dir1-to-dir3